# SSRS Indicator arrow percent change

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to apply an indicator arrow that feeds from a variance Percentage as per screenshot. The only options available within the indicator require me to set a start and end, however. The column that I wish to reference merely shows % change. This can be positive 0.9% for example or negative -2.3%. When working with the percentage change in this way how do you apply a start and end? Ideally, I would like simply to say green up arrow if >0 or red down arrow if less than 0. (right pointing orange arrow if 0 to show no change). Have been google(ing)[image] for a couple of hours now and cannot find a working solution.

The arrows do not work as all currently show Green and up.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it will solve your issue:
[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9da1c613-c23d-43e2-9900-69d6e20a28c1/indicator-expression?forum=sqlreportingservices)

It basically doesn't use the values but has an expression for the colour instead.